# jQuery mouseup function on left mouse button only?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, mouseup

I have this element which animates on a `mouseup` function, but right now, it works for both the left **and** right buttons. Is there any way to only use the **left** button?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").mouseup(function() {
        top: "-101%"
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't replicate your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/5etzp/

Comment: Well, as you can see, if you click with the *left* mouse button, it displays the alert, which is fine. But you can also use the *right* mouse button, and I want to disable right-button functionality.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be platform-specific. Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/5etzp/1/

Comment: Perfect! It works. Thanks. If you want to answer the question with that solution I would be happy to accept it. Otherwise I'll answer it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check to see which mouse button was pressed using `e.which` (`1` is primary, `2` is middle and `3` is secondary):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").mouseup(function(e) {
        if (e.which != 1) return false;    // Stops all non-left-clicks

        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: For me `event.which` returned different values in different browsers. `event.button` worked for me (0 = left, 1 = middle, 2 = right).

Comment: @panzi: Are you using jQuery? If so, what version?

Comment: Yes, I use jQuery 1.9.1.