# onClick not working with single click in IE 11

Tags: jquery, html, object

I am trying to play/pause the video when a user clicks anywhere on the video. The problem is that it is working on the double click in IE 11 and for all the other browsers, it is working perfectly with single left click. Following is my code.

```
var obj = "<object id=\"video\" onClick=\"clicked('video')\" data=\"data:application/x-silverlight-2,\" type=\"application/x-silverlight-2\" width=\"" + width1 + "%\" height=\"" + height1 + "%\">" +
                "<param name=\"onLoad\" value=\"pluginLoad\" />" +
                "<param name=\"source\" value=\"player.xap\"/>" +
                "<param name=\"initParams\" value=\"sourceurl=" + url + "\" />" +
                "</object>";
```

videoClicked method is as follows"

```
function clicked(ID) {
    $("video").css("cursor", "pointer");
    var mediaElementName = "mediaPlayer";
    var host = document.getElementById(ID);
    var s = host.content.findName(mediaElementName).CurrentState;
    if (s == "Paused")
        host.content.findName(mediaElementName).Play();
    else
        host.content.findName(mediaElementName).Pause();
}
```

I want it to work with a single left click. When I am using onmousedown, it is working perfectly on IE 11 as well. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not get the element with jquery and let jquery attach the click handler.

Comment: You mean like this $("video").click(function (){...}); ? It did not work.

Comment: You forgot the `#` before `video` :). See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't want to attach the handlers in html, or by yourself. You'll get into loads of these cross browser issues.

Try this:

```
$("#video").mouseup(function(e) {
    if (e.which != 1) return false;    // Stops all non-left-clicks
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Comment: This is not working either with a double click or a single click.

Comment: Then you are going to have to handle the click event in silverlight. If you don't have control over that, I don't know the answer.

Comment: I tried this $("body").on("click", "object", function(){alert("clicked");}); but still it is working on double click only.

Comment: Isn't there a mouse up event you could use?

Comment: But that works on right click too. I just want to left click. mouseup is working fine with single left or right click.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048344/jquery-mouseup-function-on-left-mouse-button-only

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Can you please tell me why this thing $("#video").css("cursor", "pointer"); is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because you're not passing a function to onClick, you're invoking a function. To fix this, return a function from clicked, which closes around the id `"video"`

```
function clicked(ID) {
    return function() {
      $("video").css("cursor", "pointer");
      var mediaElementName = "mediaPlayer";
      var host = document.getElementById(ID);
      var s = host.content.findName(mediaElementName).CurrentState;
      if (s == "Paused")
          host.content.findName(mediaElementName).Play();
      else
          host.content.findName(mediaElementName).Pause();
    }
}
```

This is assuming that in other circumstances there will be IDs other than video, otherwise you could just hardcode the value and not return a function.

Or if this seems complex, simply get the ID of the element by reading it from the event object:

```
function clicked(e) {
    var host = e.target;
    var ID = host.id;
    $("video").css("cursor", "pointer");
    var mediaElementName = "mediaPlayer";
    var s = host.content.findName(mediaElementName).CurrentState;
    if (s == "Paused")
        host.content.findName(mediaElementName).Play();
    else
        host.content.findName(mediaElementName).Pause();
}
```

but then you should adjust your HTML as so, passing a reference to the clicked function

```
var obj = "<object id=\"video\" onClick=\"clicked\" data=\"data:application/x-silverlight-2,\" type=\"application/x-silverlight-2\" width=\"" + width1 + "%\" height=\"" + height1 + "%\">" +
                "<param name=\"onLoad\" value=\"pluginLoad\" />" +
                "<param name=\"source\" value=\"player.xap\"/>" +
                "<param name=\"initParams\" value=\"sourceurl=" + url + "\" />" +
                "</object>";
```

Comment: it's incredibly hard to diagnose without a fiddle or something of that irk. i suggest you do that and you will likely get the answer to your problem a lot quicker